# Meaning of "kill off" in context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

So here is the sentence:

> Since Saudi Arabia's failed attempt in 2014 to kill off shale oil, the Saudis and Russians have been giving unconventional American oil a free ride. [(cnn.com)](https://edition.cnn.com/2020/04/23/perspectives/american-oil-boom-end/index.html)

What I understand here is that the Saudis attempted to kill off **the competition** of shale oil exportations.

Then I found a similar use of *kill off* (**competition** implicit/omitted as well):

> Opec bid to kill off US shale sends oil price down to 2009 low [(theguardian.com)](https://www.theguardian.com/business/2015/dec/07/opec-plan-kill-us-shale-oil-price-down-seven-year-low)

If I am right, is that usage of *kill off* (omitting **competition**) specific to market-related subjects?

Do you have any more examples of less obvious usages of *kill off* like this?

Question 2: why is American oil considered *"unconventional"* in first sentence?

Question 3: is *"free ride"* used above despite of Saudis and Russian's willingness to give US advantage? Ou should we imply by *"free ride"* that both countries have been *allowing/permitting* US to take advantage?

Thanks!

Comment: ***kill off someone/something***
— phrasal verb with kill verb [ I/T ]. (Cambridge Dictionary)

 
- to destroy or remove someone or something completely:
*Killing off predators such as grizzly bears could throw the ecosystem out of balance. - 
The worship of celebrities has killed off common sense in America .*

Comment: ***a free ride*** - 
 
an opportunity or advantage that someone gets without having done anything to deserve it: - 
*Just because he was the boss's son didn't mean Tim got a free ride.*. (Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: Shale oil has a break even price around 40/50 USD  per barrel, that means that al a lower market price like the current one 20/25  USD p/b shale oil producers are losing money and will eventually exit the oil market leaving traditional oil producing countries like Russia and Saudi Arabia , which have lower break even prices, larger market shares.

Comment: *Question 2: why is American oil considered "unconventional" in first sentence?* It is not = "**shale** oil is considered unconventional" - Use a search engine for "shale oil", and see how the source differs from conventional oil extraction.

Comment: @Hachi Thanks I know the dictionary definition. My question was more about this short form "*kill off shale oil*" meaning "*kill off small shale oil producers*" and if that kind of omission also happen in other usages of *kill off*